# Dynamic reading xml data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a xml data schema like below. All I need is to read the xml data and store it in a temp table. The columns are dynamic (the columns below are samples only), but the attributes are constant. I am expecting the result below.

```
BandCode BandDescription BandName Code     Country Currency Pay1_11  Pay1_12  Pay1_13  Pay1_14  Pay1_15
123440   Band-A          Band1    1234567  Germany  US      10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00  
123441   Band-B          Band2    1234567  Germany  US      10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00
```

Sample xml data

```
<CookedData>
   <row RowNumber="1">
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandCode" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="123440"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandDescription" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Band-A"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandName" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Band1"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="1234567"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Country" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Germany"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Currency" DataType="MONEY" Value="US"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_11" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_12" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_13" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_14" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_15" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
   </row>
   <row RowNumber="2">
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandCode" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="123441"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandDescription" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Band-B"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="BandName" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Band2"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="1234567"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Country" DataType="VARCHAR(3000)" Value="Germany"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Currency" DataType="MONEY" Value="US"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_11" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_12" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_13" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_14" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_15" DataType="MONEY" Value="10000.00"/>
   </row>
</CookedData>
```

I have researched on how to do this, however the sample code that I have found is for static columns only.

Comment: The attribute are constant mean that the attribute names are constant or that the attribute values are within a known list?

Comment: @Serpiton- the attribute name are constant. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the query dynamically.

This code uses the information from first row node `/CookedData/row[1]/Column` to get the column names and datatypes.

This will not work with your XML because you had `money` specified as the datatype for the column `Currency`. You need to change that to something else.

```sql
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) =
'select '+
  (
  select ',T.X.value(''Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "'+T.ColName+'"][1]/@Value'','''+T.DataType+''') as '+quotename(T.ColName)
  from (
       select T.X.value('@DestinationColumnCode', 'nvarchar(128)') as ColName,
              T.X.value('@DataType', 'nvarchar(128)') as DataType
       from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/row[1]/Column') as T(X)
       ) as T
  for xml path(''), type
  ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)')+' '+
'from @XML.nodes(''/CookedData/row'') as T(X)';

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16908)

The dynamically built query looks like this:

```sql
select T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "BandCode"][1]/@Value','VARCHAR(3000)') as [BandCode],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "BandDescription"][1]/@Value','VARCHAR(3000)') as [BandDescription],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "BandName"][1]/@Value','VARCHAR(3000)') as [BandName],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Code"][1]/@Value','VARCHAR(3000)') as [Code],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Country"][1]/@Value','VARCHAR(3000)') as [Country],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Currency"][1]/@Value','CHAR(2)') as [Currency],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_11"][1]/@Value','MONEY') as [Pay1_11],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_12"][1]/@Value','MONEY') as [Pay1_12],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_13"][1]/@Value','MONEY') as [Pay1_13],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_14"][1]/@Value','MONEY') as [Pay1_14],
       T.X.value('Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_15"][1]/@Value','MONEY') as [Pay1_15] 
from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/row') as T(X)
```