# SQL Server: how import XML with node's fields

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sql-import-wizard

I'm following [this guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/) that is teaching me how to import an XML file to SQL Server.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis 0.46">
  <bounds minlon="-180.00000" minlat="-90.00000" maxlon="180.00000" maxlat="90.00000" origin="http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6"/>
  <node id="1014954" version="5" timestamp="2016-01-09T23:33:09Z" uid="1894634" user="Wikilux" changeset="36472980" lat="46.4928487" lon="7.5628558">
    <tag k="url" v="www.cine-rex.ch"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Ciné Rex"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="cinema"/>
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.cine-rex.ch/kino.shtml"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Landstrasse"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="18"/>
  </node>
  <node id="20823872" version="7" timestamp="2017-09-12T15:19:00Z" uid="364" user="Edward" changeset="51976823" lat="52.2062941" lon="0.1346864">
    <tag k="name" v="Vue Cambridge"/>
    <tag k="screen" v="8"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="cinema"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="Vue Cinemas"/>
    <tag k="wikidata" v="Q39197413"/>
    <tag k="cinema:3D" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="The Grafton Centre"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="CB1 1PS"/>
  </node>
  <node id="20922159" version="12" timestamp="2017-09-12T15:19:00Z" uid="364" user="Edward" changeset="51976823" lat="52.2028721" lon="0.1234498">
    <tag k="name" v="Arts Picturehouse"/>
    <tag k="screen" v="3"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="cinema"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="City Screen Limited"/>
    <tag k="wikidata" v="Q39197264"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Cambridge"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="no"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="St Andrew&apos;s Street"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="GB"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="CB2 3AR"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="38-39"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

so I first imported the XML this way:

```
CREATE DATABASE OPENXMLTesting
GO
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\franc\Desktop\cinema.osm', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

And then imported `id`, `lat` and `long` from each `<node>`:

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT id, lat, lon
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'osm/node')
WITH 
(
id [varchar](50) '@id',
lat [varchar](100) '@lat',
lon [varchar](100) '@lon'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Perfect, it works!

But now I'm stuck. What do I need to do in order to create 2 more columns with `name` and `website`?

[image]

Because the `<tag>` is always the same and I need to take the `v=` in behalf of what is the vale of  `k=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **also** do it with native XQuery support in SQL Server, without having to resort to the legacy `OPENXML` calls which are known for memory leaks and other problem.

Just use this code instead:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

SELECT
    id = xc.value('@id', 'int'),
    lon = xc.value('@lon', 'decimal(20,8)'),
    lat = xc.value('@lat', 'decimal(20,8)'),
    name = xc.value('(tag[@k="name"]/@v)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    website = xc.value('(tag[@k="website"]/@v)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/osm/node') AS XT(XC)
```

And I also recommend to **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype - here, the `id` looks like an `INT` - so use it as such - and `lat` and `lon` are clearly `DECIMAL` values ; don't just convert everything to strings because you're too lazy to figure out what to use!

Answer (score 0):

Dammit, I found the solution by myself thanks to [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802959/import-xml-node-into-sql-sever-dynamically-with-conditional-statement):

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT id, lat, lon,name,website
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'osm/node')
WITH 
(
id [varchar](50) '@id',
lat [varchar](100) '@lat',
lon [varchar](100) '@lon',
name [varchar](100) '(tag[@k="name"]/@v)[1]',
website [varchar](500) '(tag[@k="website"]/@v)[1]'
)
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```